# check if field is substring of a string or text search on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Need to check if the field is a substring of the given input string, insensitive mode.

**Sample Doc :**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e6ffe413f71835ae3aa4b60"),
    "f" : "Paul",
    "id" : 11811,
    "l" : "Green",
    "r" : 64
  }
```

if string is **Paul Green** I want to get this item so I tried to do this query:

```
db.getCollection('players').find({$or: [{'f': {'$regex': 'Paul Green', '$options': 'i'}},{'l': {'$regex': 'Paul Green', '$options': 'i'}}]})
```

that leads no results.
I also want that searches like **pele** will give me **pelè**

How can I achieve that ?

Comment: Do you really have to search 'Paul Green' against `f` & `l` ? Can't you split it into two parts & search against fields ? Cause your query would check pass'd in string is subString of field but doesn't check field is subString of pass'd in value

Comment: I have to search it as it is

Comment: With that condition there is a way you could get docs but we can't use collation on it :: `pele will give me pelè` can't be done..

Comment: Give me partial suggestion

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Answer :**

As I've understood you wanted to implement search feature, then you can look into [text-index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/index.html) in MongoDB which specially implemented for text searches, From my experience of implementing text searches like **fuzzy/partial/full text/diacritic/case-insensitive** text search is very helpful.

So What I would suggest is since you're searching against two fields `f` & `l` - I would recommend merging two into a single field `fl` & create a text index on it that way your queries target one field which is more effective for searches, Check below recommendation :

**Step 1:** In case if you have not created a merged field you can do it now by this query on MongoDB v `>=4.2` (In lower version you need to find a way to do either `Read Coll & update field` or `use aggregation + $out`) :

```
db.collection.update({},[{$addFields : {'fl': { $concat: [ "$f", " ", "$l" ] }}}],{multi:true})
```

**Step 2:** Create a text index on `fl` field :

```
db.collection.createIndex( { fl: "text" } )
```

**Step 3:** You can do searches like below, An optional projection `{fl :0}` to remove `fl` field in response.

```
db.collection.find( { $text: { $search: "Paul Green" } }, {fl :0} )
```

**Note :** Now you can get all docs where either `f` or `l` has **Paul or Green or PAUL or GREEN or PAUL GREEN or Greèn or PAU or Pau or Gre or GRE** so most of this get sorted out. You still look into below approach if you're not looking into text searches.

---

**Actual Answer :**

Usually when you wanted to check an input value existing in a string field - you would use regex expressions to get filtered docs.

But as you wanted to pass in a string `'Paul Green'` & check a field is a sub-string of pass'd input then normal regex doesn't help you. But if you're using MongoDB version `4.2` you can do few things as below :

**Query 1 :**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  /** Add a field which will be true if any of the field 'f' or 'l' is a sub-string of input (Case-insensitive) */
  {
    $addFields: {
      result: {
        $or: [
          { $regexMatch: { input: "Paul Green", regex: "$f", options: "i" } }, /** Usually input is field & regex is actual input value, we tricked it for our requirement */
          { $regexMatch: { input: "Paul Green", regex: "$l", options: "i" } }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  /** Filter for all docs where result field is true (Which leave docs where 'f' or 'l' is sub-string) */
  { $match: { result: true } },
  /** Remove added field result */
  { $project: { result: 0 } }
]);
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EKCv-8IhccY)

**Note :** Above query would work even if send input string like `'PaulGreen'` but the downside would be it doesn't given you results as you're looking to do : **searches like pele will give me pelè**, Cause if you wanted to get that kind of data, then you need to use collation which cannot be used if we use [$regexMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/regexMatch/index.html). So based upon your data you can do as given below :

**Query 2 :**

Split string based upon spaces **['Paul', 'Green']** & pass in query :

```
db.collection.aggregate(
  /** Filter docs if any of the word exists in any of the fields 'f' or 'l' */
  [
    {
      $match: {
        $or: [
          { f: { $in: ["Paul", "Green"] } },
          { l: { $in: ["Paul", "Green"] } }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  { collation: { locale: "fr", strength: 1 } } // Applied collation ignores case & diacritics
);
```

**Note :** Above query might mostly get your work done with MongoDB versions > `3.4`, but would not work if you wanted to search something like `'PaulGreen'`, For some reason this query's collation isn't working in mongodb playground - Please test it on actual database.

Comment: and Gre(the initials)

Comment: @MD10 : I've not got it, Do you wanted to pass in `Pau` & `Gre` as inputs *(or)* for same input `Paul Green` do you want to get docs where field values can be `Pau` or `Gre` ?

Comment: my goal is to implement search like that https://www.futbin.com/

Comment: @MD10 : Ok in mongo there is no direct way to do what you're looking for !! When you pass in `Paul Green` you can't get docs with `pre` or `gre` unless you split your input string & pass as input. Your best bet would be **Query1** or Since you're looking for `Pau` or `Gre` you could split `Paul Green` into `['Pau', 'Paul', 'Green', 'Gre']` from code & do use `Query2`.

Comment: alright you can split, give me some query suggestion please.

Comment: @MD10 : For split & search you can do it thru `Query 2` but to actually implement text searches on MongoDB you could use updated answer..

Comment: thanks a lot for your effort you are awesome! however, it doesnt work for me since it matches full words only.. I need ron to give me ronaldo for example.. and ssi give me messi, something close to contains()

Comment: @MD10 : Yes is would a bit of partial but not everything related to partial searches, So you've combined multiple things, which is leading to multiple failures, Please post a question with all scenarios noted down ! Also not all things we do for searching isn't supported by MongoDB itself, Passing `Paul Green` & matching over `Paul/Green/pau/gre` is completely different than passing in 'Pau'.

Comment: I want the inputs: Lio, nel, ssi, Lionel, Mess, Lione, Messi, etc ... will yield me Lionel Messi- how that can be achieved ?