# Partial string match in mongodb array using mongoose

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I've got a MongoDB collection, which looks like this:

```js
// sites
// note that these urls all have paths, this is important.
// The path can only be longer, e.g. amazon.com/Coffee-Mug
[
  {
    name: "MySite",
    urls: ['google.com/search', 'amazon.com/Coffee', 'amazon.com/Mug']
  },
  {
    name: "OtherSite",
    urls: ['google.com/search', 'microsoft.com/en-us']
  }
]
```

What I'm trying to do is the following:

```
class Service {
  /**
   * @param url Is a full url, like "https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow"
   * or "https://www.amazon.com/Coffee-Program-Ceramic-Makes-Programmers/dp/B07D2XJLLG/"
   */
  public async lookup(findUrl: string) {
    const trimmed = trim(findUrl); // remove variables and https, but NOT the path!
    // return the "Site" in which the base url is matched with the full url
    // see description below
  }
}
```

For example, using these cases

**Case 1:**

- `url = 'https://www.amazon.com/Coffee-Program-Ceramic-Makes-Programmers/dp/B07D2XJLLG/'`
- returned site(s): `[MySite]`

**Case 2:**

- `url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow'`
- returned site(s): `[MySite, OtherSite]`

**Case 3 (same as case 1 but with other value):**

- `url = 'https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/surface'`
- returned site(s): `[OtherSite]`

**Case 4 (when not to match):**

- `url = 'https://microsoft.com/nl-nl'`
  OR
- `url = 'https://microsoft.com'`
- returned site(s): `[]`

I've tried to do something like this:

```js
Site.find({ url: { $in: trimmed }})
```

Above kind of works, but the problem is, this only does exact matches. I want to match the url from MongoDB with the url provided by the function. How does one do this?

I've received the suggestion to use [check if field is substring of a string or text search on MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60783023/check-if-field-is-substring-of-a-string-or-text-search-on-mongodb), but this is too inaccurate. I can basically enter the base domain without a path and it will find it, this is definitely not supposed to be happening.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [check if field is substring of a string or text search on MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60783023/check-if-field-is-substring-of-a-string-or-text-search-on-mongodb)

Comment: @TobiasS. This does not seem to work, it's way too inaccurate. The path of the subdomain is important to match as well

Comment: did you try it with the aggregation as the second part of the answer suggests?

Comment: @TobiasS. I did, but the `regexMatch` aggregation only works on strings, not string arrays. The `match` does not return anything at all. Using:
```js
db.getCollection("sites").aggregate([ { $match: { $or: [ { urls: { $in: ["microsoft.com/en-us/dadadadada/blablabla"] } } ] } } ], { collation: { locale: "en", strength: 1 } });
```
Nonetheless, `regexMatchAll` seems to be a thing for arrays, but that's something I'm figuring out currently.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use `$reduce` and `$filter` to iterate both over the sites and urls, matching them with `regexMatch`. Then, since the requested output is an array of urls, not array of objects, we can use `$facet` to handle the case of no matches at all.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {$expr: {
      $gt: [{
        $size: {
          $reduce: {
            input: urls_array,
            initialValue: [],
            in: {$concatArrays: [
                "$$value",
                {$filter: {
                    input: "$urls",
                    as: "url",
                    cond: {$regexMatch: {input: "$$this", regex: "$$url"}}
                 }}
             ]}
           }
         }
      }, 0]
  }}},
  {$facet: {res: [{$group: {_id: 0, res: {$addToSet: "$name"}}}]}},
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: {$mergeObjects: [{res: []}, {$first: "$res"}]}}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VeeIaIG3Msp)

Comment: This is great! Is it also possible to return the entire collection of documents in `res` instead of just `$name`?

Comment: Sure, in that case use only the `$match` step and remove the two last steps. You will get an answer which is an array of original documents that match the conditions

Answer (score 2):

I don't think of any straight way, You can use aggregation operators, but it will execute slowly because it will not use the index, if you really wanted to then I have added an approach below,

- `$expr` enables to use of aggregation operators in the query part
- `$map` to iterate loop of `urls` array, this will return a boolean values
- `$replaceAll` to replace `/` to `.` in the URL string
- `$regexMatch` to match the input string with an above-generated string that will input as a regular expression string, this will return true if the string pattern matches otherwise false
- `$in` to check if the above value has true or not

```
Site.find({
  $expr: {
    $in: [
      true,
      {
        $map: {
          input: "$urls",
          in: {
            $regexMatch: {
              input: trimmed, // your input variable
              regex: {
                $replaceAll: {
                  input: "$$this",
                  find: "/",
                  replacement: "."
                }
              },
              options: "i"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6vDLAhggfOA)